# Переопределить действие тэга в блоке VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Создаю лист ссылок в одном из компонентов

```
<a :href="'/catalog/category/edit?id=' + node.id" class="label font-weight-bold">{{ node.name }}</a>
```

вывожу вот так в родительском компоненте:

```
 <tree :tree-data="tree"></tree>
```

В итоге у меня есть отрендеренный блок div заполненный ссылками.
Мне нужно, что бы, при нажатии на ссылку происходил не переход на другую страницу, а просто эта ссылка меняла цвет и отдавала мне node.id и node.name.

Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

```js
data() {
  return {
    activeLink: null
  }
},
methods: {
  addActiveLink(node, index) {
    this.activeLink = index
    console.log(node)
  }
}
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a @click.prevent="addActiveLink(node, index)" v-for="(node, index) in nodes" :key="index" :href="'/catalog/category/edit?id=' + node.id" class="label font-weight-bold" :class="activeLink === index && 'active'">{{ node.name }}</a>
```

Comment: ругается на v-for

Comment: Ну вы хотя бы синтаксис минимально изучили

Comment: v-for сразу дописал с in nodes, но там другое было, что лист nodes устанавливается в другом компоненте сразу с нужной разметкой. Поэтому просто сделал вот так:  this.target.style.color = 'red';
      console.log(event.target);